# Splitting Data Frame and write a .csv file for each split

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R (points_t3) with 20 million records and I am looking to split into even chuncks in a same order and write a .csv file for each chunk. I was able to split the data using the below code:

```
n = 20
split(points_t3, factor(sort(rank(row.names(points_t3))%%n)))
```

Any suggestions on how to use this split and able to write data into 20 separate csv files in the directory path defined in R. Thanks,

Comment: Use `lapply` to write each element of the list returned by `split` to the required .csv file.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. The tips and the linked helped. I used this that seems to be working perfectly and getting me output in 20 csv files: lapply(names(points_t3), function(x){
  write_csv(points_t3[[x]], paste(x, ".csv", sep = ""))
})